# Can't pass implementation to method declaring generic interface (Java)

Tags: java, generics

Two attempts at passing in my generic class in the MyTest class below. The Strategy hierarchy seems fine, but declaring methods with the generic interface as an argument has problems. How do I resolve this?

```
interface Node {}

class NodeImpl implements Node {}

interface Strategy <N extends Node> {

    void setNode(N node);

}

class MyStrategy implements Strategy<NodeImpl> {

    @Override
    public void setNode(NodeImpl node) {
    }

}

class MyTest {

    void test1(Strategy<? extends Node> s) {
        s.setNode(new NodeImpl()); // compile error
    }

    void test2(Strategy<Node> s) {
        s.setNode(new NodeImpl());
    }

    void v() {
        test1(new MyStrategy());
        test2(new MyStrategy()); // compile error
    }
}
```

Test1 compile error:
The method setNode(capture#1-of ? extends Node) in the type Strategy is not applicable for the arguments (NodeImpl)

Test 2 compile error:
The method test2(Strategy) in the type MyTest is not applicable for the arguments (MyStrategy)

The MyTest class is part of an inheritance hierarchy, I wish to keep the test1() or test2() method generic, being able to pass in any Strategy implementation

Comment: Test1 fails because you violate the PECS rule. You use an upper bound on a consumed type.

Comment: Marko - I think you are saying do test1(Strategy<? super Node> s) {} This solves that compile error but I still can't call the method as I still get the same compile error as in test2, that the method 'is not applicable for the arguments (MyStrategy)'

Comment: Since you have `s.set (new NodeImpl())`, this clearly asks for the signature to be `Strategy <? super NodeImpl>`. That precisely delineates the set of all strategies compatible with what your method does to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test1 and test2 can compile if you use `NodeImpl` instead of Node (generics is strongly typed).
About Test1, as per Marko suggestion, you should use `Strategy <? super NodeImpl>` into method signature.

Comment: This is the essence of the problem, so accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

This appears to solve the problem, but it's a bit clunky.
I'm also interested in any design comments within the scope of this example code.

```
interface Node {}

class NodeImpl implements Node {}

interface Strategy <N extends Node> {

    void setNode(N node);

    Class<N> getType();
}


class MyStrategy implements Strategy<NodeImpl> {

    @Override
    public void setNode(NodeImpl node) {
    }

    @Override
    public Class<NodeImpl> getType() {
        return NodeImpl.class;
    }
}

class MyTest {

    <T extends Node> void test3(Strategy<T> s) {    
        s.setNode(s.getType().cast(new NodeImpl()));
    }

    void v() {
        test3(new MyStrategy());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that as the original example stands this is an overly complex solution that does the same as Marko has suggested. I can see that NodeImpl is fixed and that any Strategy<NodeImpl> implementation can still be used with either solution.  However it seems my example is incomplete, so I will add further context tomorrow.